# Get all children of a node in javascript

Tags: javascript, children, textnode

I want to get all children of `<p>`.

HTML:

```
<p id="p">nodlist is an <i> ordered <b>collection of node</b> objects that are </i>children of the current element.<font color="blue"> If the element</font> has no children, then contains no node.</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var childrens = [];

function getchilds(node){       

    if(node.nodeType == 1){
    var childnodes = node.childNodes;

        for(i=0; i<childnodes.length; i++){

            var child = childnodes[i];
            if(child.nodeType == 1)
            getchilds(child);

       }
    }else
    childrens.push(node);
}

var childnodes = document.getElementById('p').childNodes;       
for(i=0; i<childnodes.length; i++){

    getchilds(childnodes[i]);

}
```

but `childrens[]`  is:

0 : nodlist is an

1 : ordered

2 : collection of node

3 : objects that are

4 : has no children, then contains no node.

`children of the current element` and `If the element` have missed, and when I add `<a>` element like `<a href="url"> link </a>` to `p` tag, the script gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using a global variable `i` for the loops which means you're going to miss elements when returning from an inner function call. Change it to

```
for(var i=0; i<childnodes.length; i++){
```

in both loops.